# Ruby on Rails assetpipeline not loading

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, asset-pipeline

In my ruby on rails application I have a chance_avatar popup which I load it through an ajax call. I have created change_avatar.coffe and try to load it when the popup is shown. When I render the popup , the function in it is not called.

In my dashboard.html.erb I have this following code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal-dialog fade-scale">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div style="height: 100%;width: 100%" id="id_model_content">

           <!-- will be filled with an ajax call -->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When a custom action is triggered, I'm calling this code:

```
$("#id_model_content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'popup')%>");
```

And finally I have this _popup.html.erb file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'popup', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<div>
   Popup content
</div>
```

I have popup.coffe file added in assetpileline via following code:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += [ 'popup.coffee' ]
```

popup.coffe:

```
#= require_self
alert('called')
```

This function is not called.

On the other hand, if I add following code direct into dashboard.html.erb
it's called,

I couln't figure out what I'm missing,

Any suggestions,

Thanks.

Comment: Try popup.js instead of popup.coffe